# I just created Ubuntu Gnome bootable usb. How to know whether it is BIOS of UEFI?

Tags: live-usb

I created a Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.03 (64 bits) bootable usb using Startup Disk Creator and I am wondering whether there is a way (maybe with Gparted) to check if it is a BIOS or UEFI boot.

Checking the USB with Disks (Ubuntu 16.04), this is what I see:

[image: First Partition of USB]

[image: Second Partition of USB]

As you can see, in the Second Partition it says: Partition Type EFI(FAT-12/16/32). Does this mean this is NOT BIOS?

Cheers

Comment: It should work in both modes.

Comment: Unless you modified the Ubuntu iso, it is able to boot both in UEFI or Legacy BIOS mode.

Comment: But how do I ensure that it will install UEFI

Comment: That depends on whether you boot it in UEFI or in Legacy BIOS mode. There has to be a setting in your UEFI setup menu or boot menu.

Comment: Ah..cool..cheers. I a bit new to this.

Answer (score 4):

1. Depending on how you created the USB boot drive, it works in both [U]EFI and BIOS (alias CSM alias legacy) mode. If you *clone* the iso file to the USB drive, it will boot in both boot modes. In the original question I can see the `iso9660` partition, which indicates a cloned system.  And you set the boot mode in the UEFI/BIOS menu system, which is part of the computer.
2. You may want to test if your live system is running in UEFI or BIOS mode. An installed system and a live system too is using the directory /sys/firmware/efi, so you can run the following command line,

   ```
   test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios
   ```
3. Please notice that you will install a system, that works in the current boot mode,

   - If you install in UEFI mode, the installed system will work in UEFI mode
   - If you install in BIOS alias CSM alias legacy mode, the installed system will work in BIOS mode.

Comment: That was helpful..cheers

Comment: Let us know how it works for you to install Ubuntu Gnome. Good luck :-)

Comment: Sure.. I'm still in the process of understanding the partition scheme, as it seems that I am suppose to create an ESP partition. (I am manually partitioning since I want to install windows later on..I am aware of the problems that might arise from this procedure as I've heard I'll have to do a boot repair)

Comment: It is easier to install Windows before Ubuntu. But it is also possible the other way around and to re-install the grub bootloader after you have installed Windows (and it has overwritten it).

Comment: @sudodus Yeah, isn't it simpler to run `grub-install` rather than `boot-repair`?

Comment: Yes, @wjandrea, for you and me, but a new user might prefer a GUI tool. But I think the best option is to avoid reinstalling the bootloader ;-)